# How can I return to the Philippines?

Tags: visas, overstaying, philippines

I was in the Philippines for 15 months. I was severely ill and my weight dropped from 65 kilos to 36 kilos. I wanted to come back to the UK for treatment. I ran out of money in Philippines due to medical costs, but I finally managed to raise money to leave the Philippines.

I went to immigration and I requested that I leave. Having left, I still have to pay ₱50,000 as penalty, which I cannot do now. I am back to normal after 2 years treatment. I want to go to the Philippines again. If I pay the penalty, how soon can I go back?

I support two children in the Philippines so I want to see them. I have full documentation evidence to support this. Can someone tell me how long before I can go back?

Comment: What is the cause of the ₱50,000 penalty, without that information a proper answer cannot be given.

Comment: Also, what do you want to do in the Philippines? Do you want to live there with your children?

Comment: Also, what is your nationality? Please [edit] your question.